# Как передать выражение как переменную в функцию?

Tags: c++, c, функции

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
float x_n=-1.2, x_k=-0.5, epsilon;
void metodpoldil(float a, float b, float eps){
    float sum, x;
    if ((a*a*a*a+0.2*a*a*a-0.4*a*a-1.4*a-1.2)==0){
        printf("%f", a);
    }
    else if((b*b*b*b+0.2*b*b*b-0.4*b*b-1.4*b-1.2)==0){
            printf("%f", b);
        }
    while (b-a>eps){
        sum=(b-a)/2;
        x=a+sum;
        if ((a*a*a*a+0.2*a*a*a-0.4*a*a-1.4*a-1.2)!=(x*x*x*x+0.2*x*x*x-0.4*x*x-1.4*x-1.2)){
            b=x;    
        }
        else{
            a=x;
        }
    }
    printf("The x is %f", x);
}
int main() {
    printf("Epsilon = ");
    scanf("%f", &epsilon);
    metodpoldil(x_n, x_k, epsilon);
    return 0;
}
```

Код вычисляет с точностью до Epsilon x, в интервале [-1.2, -0.5], методом половинного деления. Как мне передать в мою функцию metodpoldil, как параметр, вот такое выражение: f(x)=x^4+0.2*x^3-0.4*x^2-1.4^x-1.2=0?

Comment: Может, вам лучше написать соответствующую функцию и передать на нее указатель? Ну, можно и лямбда-выражение, конечно... Если С++.

Comment: А как реализовать с помощью второй функции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
double f(double a)
{
    return (((a+0.2)*a-0.4)*a-1.4)*a-1.2;
}

void metodpoldil(double (*func)(double), double a, double b, double eps){
    double sum, x;
    if (func(a) == 0){
        printf("%f", a);
    }
    else if(func(b) == 0){
            printf("%f", b);
        }
    while (b-a>eps){
        sum=(b-a)/2;
        x=a+sum;
        if (func(a) != func(x)){
            b=x;    
        }
        else{
            a=x;
        }
    }
    printf("The x is %lf", x);
}
int main() {
    printf("Epsilon = ");
    scanf("%lf", &epsilon);
    metodpoldil(f, x_n, x_k, epsilon);
    return 0;
}
```

О том, верно ли и эффективно ли работает весь ваш код — ничего не говорю, не смотрел. Отвечаю только на вопрос, как передать функцию в функцию...